# Very common Expression evaluation

Tags: c++, expression

What is the way of working out:

```
int i=5;
a= ++i + ++i + ++i;
```

If we go by normal right to left evaluation, the result should be 21 (6 + 7 + 8) .

I remember studying in school, that the answer was 24(8 + 8 + 8)

But I tried it on CodeBlocks, www.ideone.com, ie gcc 4.8.1 compiler and now I get 22.
Could someone please explain the reason

Comment: There is no way of working it out.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: A nice quote from one of the questions that this is a possible duplicate of: 

"Use statements which the language standard actually tells you what they will do. Do not use undefined behaviour and then wonder what's going on. "

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner Wow! I read your quote and I seemed to remember that it was from me, then I [looked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc#comment757581_949443) and it was, actually :-) That's not bad for being from 2009.

Comment: @DanielDaranas that's awesome actually :P

Answer (score 0):

There are no [Sequence Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in that expression, so you can't work it out, it is undefined/compiler dependant.

Answer (score 0):

It is as defined by the C/C++ standards an [undefined or implementation-defined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The language standards **do not** specify the behavior, it allows the compiler implementation to choose (and is usually documented).

Also look at another StackOverflow question: [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc).

---

What GCC does in your example is the following:

```
int i = 5;
a = ++i + (++i + ++i);  // it first gets the value of i and increments it two times
a = ++i + (7 + 7);  // it then reads the new value of i, does the addition and save it as a constant in the stack
a = ++i + 14;  // it then gets the value of i and increments it
a = 8 + 14;  // it then reads the new value of i and add it to the constant
a = 22;
```

Comment: "Undefined" is very different from "implementation-defined". In this case, it's undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Since the compiler compiles and the program give a results **it is** defined.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker: No.  One of the consequences of being undefined is that the compiler can do anything, including compile it and give a result.  In fact, for undefined behavior, it is almost always the case that it does this, because it is the simplest thing to do (no need to special case it)

Comment: It is also very unlikely that a compiler documents what it will do in such a case (and the behavior can be very different with different compiler settings like optimization levels).